# Docker container with Node and Express on Mac, not showing in browser?

Tags: node.js, macos, localhost, docker, boot2docker

I'm delving into Docker and I'm trying to rack my brains on why this isn't working for me. I've read many articles and tutorials on how to setup this up and I seem to have everything in place, but my actual app just isn't showing up in the browser (`localhost:3001`). I'm using the latest version of Docker on my Mac, running Mavericks, using boot2docker. I definitely have boot2docker running as the `docker` commands run fine and I get no errors that seem to relate.

The super simple project looks like this:

```
src/
..index.js
..package.json
Dockerfile
```

The `src/index.js` file looks like this:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('Hello world!');
});

app.listen(3001);
```

The `src/package.json` file looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "node-docker-example",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "A NodeJS webserver to run inside a docker container",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
     "express": "*"
  }
}
```

The `Dockerfile` file looks like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

# make sure apt is up to date
RUN apt-get update

# install nodejs and npm
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs npm git git-core

# add source files
ADD /src /srv

# set the working directory to run commands from
WORKDIR /srv

# install the dependencies
RUN npm install

# expose the port so host can have access
EXPOSE 3001

# run this after the container has been instantiated
CMD ["nodejs", "index.js"]
```

With all of this in place, I then build it just locally:

```
$ docker build -t me/foo .
```

No problems... Then I've tried some alternative ways to make it run, but **none of these work** and I can't see any response when viewing in my browser (`localhost:3001`)

```
$ docker run -i -t me/foo
$ docker run -i -t -p 3001:3001 me/foo
$ docker run -i -t -p 127.0.0.1:3001:3001 me/foo
```

Nothing seems to work, no errors come up... Well, apart from that `localhost:3001` in the browser **does absolutely nothing**.

Please help me! I love the idea of docker, but I can't get the simplest thing running. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**boot2docker has an extra network**

There's one extra layer of networking getting in the way. Remember that boot2docker has it's own OS and additional network IP, so try `url=http://$(boot2docker ip):3001;curl -v "${url}"` from a terminal on your mac and see if that returns HTML from your express app. If so, you can browse to your app with `open "${url}"`.

I was able to take your files (thank you for posting full files!) and build and run your image locally.

**Build, run, and test it like this**

```
docker build -t foo .
docker run -i -t -p 3001:3001 foo
```

I think the key thing to note is that for `docker build` the `-t` argument means "tag" but for `docker run` it means "allocate a tty".

**Test it like this** (in a separate terminal from where it's running interactively)

```
curl -s "$(boot2docker ip):3001"
```

**Here's where you went wrong**

Or at least my guesses:

> $ docker run -i -t me/foo

doesn't map any ports

> $ docker run -i -t -p 3001:3001 me/foo

I think in theory this variant should work. If not, I'm pretty sure it's a boot2docker-specific networking issue at the IP layer.

> $ docker run -i -t -p 127.0.0.1:3001:3001 me/foo

This is telling docker to bind to loopback on the docker server, not your mac, so you'll never be able to connect to this from your mac.

Comment: Hey Peter, thanks for replying. I tried the first command you suggested, but I got this:
* About to connect() to 192.168.59.103 port 3001 (#0)
*   Trying 192.168.59.103...
* Adding handle: conn: 0x7fd0e1804000
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x7fd0e1804000) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* Failed connect to 192.168.59.103:3001; Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed connect to 192.168.59.103:3001; Connection refused

Comment: Try `CMD ["node", "index.js"]`. I don't think your express app is successfully starting and running yet, and that's my guess as to why.

Comment: Hello again... It has to be nodejs as that's how node is installed with that particular version of Ubuntu. I would usually symlink it to be "node" but I didn't in this case for simplicity. I tried it anyhow, but alas, no luck.

Comment: OK, I got your app built and running locally fine and posted my thoughts. Maybe that will get you going.

Comment: Thank you @PeterLyons ...you've cracked it for me!

Comment: setting dockerhost for browser as suggested in http://viget.com/extend/how-to-use-docker-on-os-x-the-missing-guide helped out too